# Automatic recognize new file and get the path

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

i have written a python script that reads continuously a csv file outputted and updated by a sensor and live plots some data with matplotlib.
Everytime i start recording data from the sensor it creates a new file like:

data-2020_02_27_14_42_29.csv

So everytime i have to update my script to point the correct csv file.
How i can automate this?
Is there a way to recognize the creation of a new file in a specific directory and take the name of it?

```
with open('/home/matteo/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/200213-123258-INS/data/data-2020_02_27_14_42_29.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

Thanks

Comment: How about having the script search for the newest file starting with "data-" and ending with ".csv"?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of what files there were at the start at end of your script, then get the new item by comparing the two lists.

```
def read(file):
    folder='/home/matteo/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/200213-123258-INS/data'
    start_list=[file for file in os.listdir(folder)]
    with open(os.path.join(folder,file), 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    #any other code that happens after reading the csv....

    end_list=[file for file in os.listdir(folder)]

    new_file=list(set(start_list)-set(end_list))

    #checks that a new file was found (if nothing new list is empty)
    #if it is empty, re-run function on existing file
    if new_file!=[]
        new_file=new_file[0]
    else:
        new_file=file

    #recursion to call the function on the new file we found
    read(new_file)
```